# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.parse.PPNSService

Tags: android, parse-platform

I get this java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.parse.PPNSService error when trying to use Parse SDK. I have already added the required jar into project.

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
  compile files('libs/Parse-1.10.1.jar')
  compile files('libs/PPNS-1.10.1.jar')
}
```

Does anybody had the same issue?

Comment: try this `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-1.10.1.jar')`  `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'PPNS-1.10.1.jar')` .